# Installing python API from git

Tags: python, pip

I can't figure out why I can't install https://github.com/ldilley/minestat. when I do pip install git+https://github.com/ldilley/minestat, it gives a error of Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Chuck\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-98h731vo\

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: From a quick glance, seems you just need to download or clone the repositiory. Then place `minestat.py` somewhere in your python path so you can import it.

Comment: it's not a pip package, you cant install it. if you want to use it then just put the minstat.py file in you projectand import from there as shown in example.py file.

Comment: The repo build for python has no `setup.py` file. When I try your same command to install I get `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/qz/smb2qbnj2bzft1w15htqhdmrzz6jc_/T/pip-req-build-abqhx9/setup.py'`, the `setup.py` missing for `pip`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may means that your setuptools are out of date.
You can fix this by doing: `pip install --upgrade setuptools`